# Pronunciation of coitize

Tags: pronunciation

I have not ever heard this word, but I see it in print from time to time.

Wiktionary, where I normally go to look up a word, does not list a pronunciation.

Etymologically, apparently, the co- is a prefix, hinting at the possibility of a three-syllable pronunciation analogous to "coincide" or "coindex". But on the other hand, "coitus" apparently has a two-syllable pronunciation analogous to "coin".

Curiously, neither Oxford English Dictionary nor Merriam Webster seem to list the word at all. Am I losing the plot? If not, how can I know the correct pronunciation(s)?

Comment: There's nothing curious about the fact that Wiktionary lists "words" that aren't in "mainstream" dictionaries. It's not a reliable source, so you shouldn't have Wiktionary as your *first* choice to look things up. I'm not gonna look them up, but I've no doubt the etymology of *coincide* involves ***co-*** (for "together") and ***incident***. And I bet ***coitus*** doesn't involve a ***co-*** prefix.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there's nothing unusual about the fact that dictionaries don't normally list "non-words"

Comment: 'Wiktionary, where I normally go to look up a word' - there's your problem, right there.

Comment: There is also a pattern of **izing** words for neologisms like incentivizing (because motivating wasn't good enough ... incentive).

Comment: @FumbleFingers You bet coitus doesn't involve a *co-* prefix, and claim that coitize is a "non-word", and you also say you're not going to look any of it up

Comment: Well, I speak English perfectly well, so I don't think that's unreasonable. But *your* position (treating Wiktionary as a credible "authority" from which to *learn* English) is definitely "questionable".

Comment: @FumbleFingers I did not say (anything like) that. I said I looked the word up there.

Comment: People who pronounce _coitus_ with two syllables don't know any Latin. It comes from **co-ire = go together**.

Comment: You said you "normally go to look up a word" in Wiktionary. I advised you that you should change your "normal" approach. I suggest you use a *real* dictionary, such as one of those recommended under [Learner's dictionaries](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/739/126) on ELL Meta. I see that post does actually list Wiktionary under "Other". But that's alongside Urban Dictionary, with a warning about potential inaccuracies in such crowd-sourced resources. I'd only use Wiktionary as a *last resort*, not first port of call.

Comment: @KateBunting: The full OED doesn't go that far back! I just checked *their* etymology, and it says *A borrowing from Latin. see **coit** n.* With a link to their definition for ***coition***, where the etymology stops at *A borrowing from Latin. Etymon: Latin **coitiōn-em**.* I didn't study Latin, so I can't argue with you as to whether there's a further level of etymology below those Latin terms, but if the full OED doesn't go that far back, it's probably not relevant to the needs of learners. Checking ***coincide*** immediately finds ***co-** = together* in the etymology, though.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Interesting. I was going by the 'Oxford Languages' definition, as produced by googling _coitus definition_, which says **mid 19th century: from Latin, from coire ‘go together’**

Comment: You may find this helpful [What sorts of dictionaries should we use on ELL?](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4721/9161)

Comment: @KateBunting: I can't seem to get to any alternative etymology apart from the actual full (subscription-only) OED with "oxford" in my google search term. But if I'm only actually looking for *etymology* (as opposed to previously, where I had to log in to OED to double-check that "coitize" *wasn't* in fact a word! :) then I usually go to etymonline. And there it is! *Latin coitus "a meeting together; sexual union," past participle of coire "to come together, meet," from assimilated form of com "together" (see co-) + ire (past participle itus) "to come, to go," (from PIE root *ei- "to go")*

Comment: From Etymonline.com:  "copulation, sexual intercourse," 1848, scientific use of Latin coitus "a meeting together; sexual union," past participle of coire "to come together, meet," **from assimilated form of com "together" (see co-) + ire (past participle itus) "to come, to go,"**  (from PIE root *ei- "to go").

Comment: Coitize, right now, over you...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whatever the ultimate etymology, "coitize" is formed directly from "coitus" and shares it pronunciation. But there are several acceptable pronunciations of "coitus": /ˈkəʊ.ɪ.təs/, /ˈkɔɪ.təs/ and hence there are several acceptable pronunciations of "coitize":  /ˈkəʊ.ɪ.taɪz/, /ˈkɔɪ.taɪz/

But the fact it is missing from major dictionaries is a big red flag!  This word is not a common or standard term.  It should not be used in your speech or writing in any formal or semi-formal context. (and since it is not an informal term, you shouldn't use it in a casual context either)